# MVC Beginform action = goto anchor/id on page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a MVC beginform (with JQUERY UI MOBILE AND AJAX.) When the user clicks submit, 
I would like `**<div data-role="page" id="two">**` to display on the page.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<div data-role="page" id="one">
<div data-role="header">Header stuff</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content" >  
<div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
.....DATA......
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div></div><div>

<div data-role="page" id="two">
<div data-role="header">Header stuff2</div><!-- /header -->
<div data-role="content" >  
<div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
FINISH
</div></div><div>



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this and found out I cannot return the anchor tag from MVC's controllers.  So, I redirect users from a parameter that the controller passes back:

```
if( getParameterByName("anchorID") != null) { 
    location.href = '#' + getParameterByName("anchorID");
} 

function getParameterByName(name) { 
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)') 
                    .exec(window.location.search); 
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
```

Then you should be able to get your div to view after clicking the submit.

Comment: I get blank page saying "Undefined" when I have location.href = '#two'